# How to disable delete button when all the checkboxes are disabled of a column in grid asp.net by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a grid in which I have 7 columns where all the checkboxes are
disabled. How do I disable the delete button?

In the diagram below, if all the checkboxes in the Cancel SO Line Item
column are disabled then the DEL button should be disabled.

[image: GIRD]

**.Aspx File**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cancel SO Line Item">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:checkbox ID="cbSOCan" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" EnableViewState="true"></asp:checkbox>
         </ItemTemplate>

     <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-primary" ID="btnCancelItem" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"OnClientClick="return Confirmationbox();">&nbsp;Cancel Item</asp:LinkButton>
 <asp:HiddenField id="hdnval" value=0 runat="server"/>
```

**C# code**

```
protected void btnCancelItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in gvPOItems.Rows) {
        CheckBox chkdelte = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("cbSOCan");
        HiddenField hdnval = (HiddenField)gvrow.FindControl("hdnval");
        if (chkdelte.Checked) {
            // gvAdditionalArea.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(0).Text()
            Int32 ItemNumber = Convert.ToInt32(gvrow.Cells(0).Text());
            Queries.CancelSOlineItem(ItemNumber, txtPONumber.Text);
            gvrow.Cells(7).Text() = "Cancelled";
            chkdelte.Checked = false;
            chkdelte.Enabled = false;
            hdnval.Value = 1;
}
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
{if (!IsPostBack)
int rowcount = 0;
foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in gvPOItems.Rows) {
    HiddenField hdnval = (HiddenField)gvrow.FindControl("hdnval");
    if ((hdnval.Value == 1)) {
        rowcount = rowcount + 1;
    }
}
if ((gvPOItems.Rows.Count == rowcount)) {
    btnCancelItem.Visible = false;
}
}
}
```

[image: checkbox is disabled but still showing enabled]

Comment: no answer yet..

Comment: need help c# or jS

Comment: ok not deleting it

Comment: good to know, hang on a sec

Comment: still waiting...

Comment: what happen @JaromandaX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**by Jquery**

```
disableCheckbox = function () {
                        //checked check-boxes length
                        checkedCount = $('#CP_Main_gvPOItems input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;

                        //check-boxes length
                        checkboxCount = $('#CP_Main_gvPOItems input[type=checkbox]').length;

                        //if no check-box is selected then alert
                        //                if (checkedCount == 0) {
                        //                    alert('No check-box is selected');
                        // }
                        //check for all disabled check-boxes
                        //var disableCheckBox = 0;
                        $('#CP_Main_gvPOItems input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                            if ($(this).is(':disabled')) {
                                disableCheckBox++;
                            }
                        });

                        //if all check-boxes are disabled then disable button
                        if (checkboxCount == disableCheckBox) {

                            $('#CP_Main_btnCancelItem').attr("disabled", "disabled"); //# is missing
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the state of the CheckBoxes in the RowDataBound event. If even one checkbox is enabled, set the global boolean to true and then in the footer row set the Delete Button state.

```
bool oneCheckBoxIsEnabled = false;

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow or the footer row
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //check the state of the checkbox
        //either by checking the source data for the value that would trigger the disable
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(row["isEnabledInDB"]) == true)
        {
            oneCheckBoxIsEnabled = true;
        }

        //or the state of the checkbox with findcontrol
        CheckBox cb = e.Row.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox;
        if (cb.Enabled == true)
        {
            oneCheckBoxIsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        //use the footer row to enable or disable the button
        DeleteButton.Enabled = oneCheckBoxIsEnabled;
    }
}
```

Comment: any JS solution ?

Comment: delete button is not part of Grid so will this Footer thing work ?

Comment: delete button is placed outside the grid

Comment: andcould u  pls update your answer to if any of the checkboxes aren't checked then button should be disabled @VDWWD

Comment: You need a JS solution also? And did you figure out the issue in your 4th comment?

Comment: no c# would be fine just tell how to disable the button which is the page rather than in grid. ? not figured the 4th comment(checkboxes aren't checked

Comment: In my solution `DeleteButton` is outside the grid. So if all checkboxes are disabled, so is the button, but if one is not, the button will stay clickable.

Comment: code seems to be working but the problem is that Check box is disabled but but (as shown in the above image in the Question) but during debugging it's showing enabled !!

Comment: have added another image

Comment: `disabled="disabled"` means that it is actually disabled.

Comment: if it's disabled then why during debugging it's showing enabled=true ?  @VDWWD

Comment: don't u think it will be very silly to check each row of grid (row databound) for button enable/disable